# aspose.tasks resource assignment units setting

Tags: aspose

I want export to ms project by Aspose tasks library in my program. when adding resource and resource assignments , when setting units with real work in aspose tasks, I expect work per day be : Resource work /task duration. but when open ms project file, the work per day is : units value * 8. anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/permalink/694616/695211/showthread.aspx#695211), please use Asn.Work for setting the work for the assignment and set Asn.Units as 0.5 (day)  which set 4 hours max per day. You may please follow up the same on Aspose.Tasks forum in case you have further inquiry in this regard.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.